# How can I place data in WOW64's 32 bit registry view from the NT Native API?

Tags: windows, winapi, registry, nt-native-api

I have an application where I am restricted to using the `NtCreateKey` / `ZwCreateKey` function(s). (e.g. in a driver) There is another application I don't control which runs under WOW64, which reads a value from this registry key.

I want to set the registry value such that this application can find it. However, WOW64 is implemented in `kernel32` -- so I can't pass the `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` flag like I can when using `RegOpenKeyEx`.

The easiest way seems to be to include `Wow6432Node` in the path passed to `ZwCreateKey`, but [MSDN discourages this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253.aspx):

> WOW64 defines the following symbolic links only for compatibility with existing applications that may use hardcoded registry key paths containing `Wow6432Node`. New applications should avoid using Wow6432Node in registry key paths.

This seems to put me between a rock and a hard place... how can I place data in the 32 bit registry view? The MSDN language says "avoid" -- is this a situation where `Wow6432Node` is unavoidable?

Comment: Using `Wow6432Node` in this situation seems ok to me.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I think so, but I try to avoid doing things that MSDN says not to do whenever possible.

Comment: I take it there's no chance you could get a user-mode process to make the registry changes on your behalf?

Comment: @Harry: Nope. IPC is a can of worms I don't want to open over this.

Comment: ... well, you could stick the registry settings in the ordinary 64-bit part of the registry and get the user-mode process to monitor and copy them.  But I agree that's not a *good* solution.

Comment: Looking at this again, I'd argue that this is a forwards compatibility issue - that is, the only reason not to use Wow6432Node is that it might not work in future releases of Windows - and that device drivers are never guaranteed to be forwards compatible.  So I wouldn't worry about it too much.